# Difficulty in understanding fortran arthimetic

Tags: c#, fortran, porting, fortran77

I've been trying to make sense of the following subroutine but cant seem to get it right:

```
subroutine press(ptes,Re,densm,void,svel,vis,dhyd,ht,p)
a=1.30
p=a*Re**(-1.63)*svel**2*ht/dhyd/void/densm/1000.
p=p*ptes
return
end
```

I have followed the information on arithmetic precedence mentioned [here](http://www.idris.fr/data/cours/lang/fortran/F77.html#p3.1.1), but can't seem to get the equivalent C# function(shown below) to spit out the similar output.

```
public static void calculatePressureDrop(
    float pressure_drop_coeff, 
    float re, 
    float density_massecuite, 
    float voidage, 
    float superficial_mass_velocity, 
    float viscosity, 
    float hydraulic_diameter, 
    float height_of_section, 
    ref float pressure_drop)
{
    float sel_exp_val = (float)(2 * height_of_section / hydraulic_diameter / voidage / density_massecuite / 1000.0);
    float sel_exp = (float)Math.Pow(superficial_mass_velocity, sel_exp_val);
    float sel_exp_prod = -1.63F * sel_exp;
    float re_exp = (float)Math.Pow(re, sel_exp_prod);
    pressure_drop = (float)1.30 * re_exp;
    pressure_drop = pressure_drop * pressure_drop_coeff;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The is the code in my test case that keeps failing

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPressureDropMethodV2() // Uses call by ref
    {
        float pressure_drop_coeff = 1.20000005F;
        float re = 0.000365345448F;
        float density_massecuite = 1460;
        float voidage = 0.757799625F;
        float superficial_mass_velocity = 1.53357923F;
        float hydraulic_diameter = 0.151121646F;
        float viscosity = 634.350342F;
        float height_of_section = 0.0850000009F;
        float pressure_drop = 0;
        Finless5Lib.calculatePressureDrop(pressure_drop_coeff, re, density_massecuite, voidage, superficial_mass_velocity, viscosity, hydraulic_diameter, height_of_section,ref pressure_drop);
        float expectedResult = 0.74733448F;
        //// Verify the result:
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, pressure_drop);
    }
```

When I printed the values off from Fortran, this is what I got:

> ptes =   1.20000005
>   Re =   0.000379003613
>   densm =   1460.
>   void = 0.757799625
>   svel =   1.53357923
>   vis =   611.490234
>   dhyd =   0.151121646
>   ht =   0.0850000009
>   p =   0.703936338

Please help! any advice would be helpful!

Comment: What results are you getting from each respective bit of code?  Is it possible the difference is due to rounding errors (especially on the division)?

Comment: Rather than pass in `pressure_drop` as a `ref`, why don't you just return it?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `Math.Pow(re, -1.63)`?  since ** has the highest precedence?

Comment: I'm not a specialist on fortran, but I'm pretty sure the precedence of operators has been implemented correctly. I read `(a * (pow(Re, -1.63) * pow(svel, 2) * ht)/(dhyd * void * densm * 1000)`. This piece of code proves that finding the shortest expression isn't always a good idea.

Comment: @AdamMiller don't think it is so coz the fortran output is 0.725221753 and the c# output is 53234.12

Comment: @juharr I was trying to maintain the same format as the Fortran code...I will change it asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want this

```
public static float calculatePressureDrop(
    float pressure_drop_coeff,
    float re,
    float density_massecuite,
    float voidage,
    float superficial_mass_velocity,
    float viscosity,
    float hydraulic_diameter,
    float height_of_section)
{
    return pressure_drop_coeff * 1.3F * (float)Math.Pow(re, -1.63)
           * (float)Math.Pow(superficial_mass_velocity , 2) * height_of_section 
           / hydraulic_diameter / voidage / density_massecuite / 1000F;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
float pressure_drop = calculatePressureDrop(...);
```

You're problem was that you were not giving the highest precidence to the power operators.  Also in general it's best to avoid `ref` parameters if you can.

Comment: Hi juharr, I tried the precedence earlier, but it didn't work. I also tried the solution that you have given, but with no luck. :(

Comment: @rkc88 I think you'll have to give use example input and output to help determine what the problem is then.

Comment: @rkc88 Just realized I had `1.63` instead of `-1.63`.  Try it now.

Comment: @rkc88 just tested with your input values and this seems to work after I put that negative sign in there.

Comment: It worked!!!! Although my test case is failing because functions return value = 0.7039364 & expectedResult is 0.703936338

Comment: @rkc88 you'll want to check that the values are within some small value (epsilon) of each other, as floating point math is not exact and you can get slightly different answers on different machines, different compilers, different compiler options, etc.

Comment: @casey Thanks for the info. Didn't think of different machine problem/compiler problem. Cheers

Comment: @casey Wth the problem of the test case I tried using -1.63F which gave the correct result

Answer (score 2):

I don't know FORTRAN very well, but if `**` has higher precedence than `*`, then:

`p=a*(Re**(-1.63))*(svel**2)*ht/dhyd/void/densm/1000`

Your C# seems to be doing something more like:

`p=a*(Re**((-1.63)*(svel**(2*ht/dhyd/void/densm/1000))))`

Answer (score 2):

The precedence of operators (ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010 aka Fortran 2008 cl. 7.1.3) relevant to this expression is  `**`, `*` or `/`, unary `+` or `-`, binary `+` or `-`.

The Fortran expression

```
p=a*Re**(-1.63)*svel**2*ht/dhyd/void/densm/1000.
```

is equivalent to the mathematical expression

```
p = a * (Re**(-1.63)) * (svel**2) * ht / dhyd / void / densm / 1000.0
```

combined with the other statement (`a=1.30` before and `p=p*ptes` after) yields:

```
p = 1.30 * (Re**(-1.63)) * (svel**2) * ht / dhyd / void / densm / 1000.0 * ptes
```

The multiplication and divisions are evaluated left to right.